# Angular form field to be validated when initialized

Tags: angular

I have built a template-driven form which includes a table of fields.  One data item in a row of the table has a "pathname" field like this.  (This is inside an *ngFor structure)

```
      <td>
        <mat-form-field>
          <input #fieldPath="ngModel" type="text" matInput [(ngModel)]="f.pathName"
                 name="pathname{{ row }}"
                 required appPathnameValidator appPathInUseValidator [parentId]="parent.id"
                 placeholder="Path name">
          <mat-error *ngIf="fieldPath.errors?.pattern">Path Name cannot include white space or / character.</mat-error>
          <mat-error *ngIf="fieldPath.errors?.required">Path Name is Required.</mat-error>
          <mat-error *ngIf="fieldPath.errors?.pathInUse">Path Name Is In Use</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
```

So I have one built-in and two custom validators.  These all work when the user visits the the form control and leaves it.   However the way the form is initialized it may have starting values that do not pass validation.   But the **mat-error** elements are not shown at that time.

Is there any way to force these fields to be validated without the user having to visit them?

Comment: The documentation says: `Errors are hidden initially and will be displayed on invalid form fields after the user has interacted with the element or the parent form has been submitted.` So it sounds like that is the way it works. Could you build your own error handling and not use the `mat-error` element? (Reference: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#error-messages)

Comment: You can create a custom error state matcher: https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#changing-when-error-messages-are-shown

Comment: @DeborahK your link leads to useful normative text on this topic.  I hadn't considered that this is a material issue as opposed to a regular angular issue.

Comment: @AJT_82 Oy.  That does look like the right approach

Answer (score 1):

I don't use `mat-error`,  and have complete control over when the messages appear: immediately (which is the standard angular default), only when the field has been touched, when the field has been modified (dirty), or any combination.

```
  <div class="form-group row mb-2">
    <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label"
           for="firstNameId">First Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input class="form-control"
             id="firstNameId"
             type="text"
             placeholder="First Name (required)"
             required
             minlength="3"
             [(ngModel)]=customer.firstName
             name="firstName"
             #firstNameVar="ngModel"
             [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': (firstNameVar.touched || firstNameVar.dirty) && !firstNameVar.valid }" />
      <span class="invalid-feedback">
        <span *ngIf="firstNameVar.errors?.required">
          Please enter your first name.
        </span>
        <span *ngIf="firstNameVar.errors?.minlength">
          The first name must be longer than 3 characters.
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In this code I display the message if it has been `touched` or `dirty` and its not `valid`. I assume you'd only want not `valid` if you want to display the messages immediately.

Answer (score 0):

[DeborahK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1647604/deborahk) provided me the hint I needed but I will document my solution here for the benefit of anyone who might need it.

I get access to the form via a **@ViewChild** reference.  In the template:

```
  <form #tform="ngForm" >
```

and in the component:

```
  @ViewChild('tform') form: NgForm;
```

Now after the form is built I can iterate through all the **FormControl**s like this:

```
    for (const key of Object.keys(this.form.controls)) {
      const control = this.form.controls[key];
      if (!control.valid) control.markAsTouched();
    }
```

Note that the fields are already validated so the **valid** property will be set.  However the effect of the **markAsTouched** method allows the **mat-error** elements to be displayed according to the results.